# Incorporating a SQL LIKE in a SELECT query using Twitter/typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE postal_code = ? or place_name = ? or admin_code1 = ? or admin_name2 = ? or admin_name1 = ?",
$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"]);
```

As expected when I begin to type say, New York, the dropdown box says "no places found" until an exact match for New York is found whereby the dropdown box then suggests a number of locations that match exactly New York.  Same for when I begin to type a zip code.

I modified the code to use LIKE for postal_code as follows:

```
$places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE  places.postal_code LIKE ? or place_name = ? or admin_code1 = ? or admin_name2 = ? or admin_name1 = ?",
    $_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"]);
```

However this modification has no effect.  I'd like the query to return locations based upon say typing in the beginning of a zip instead of the full zip. As I am new to SQL, I'm unsure of the syntax and what modifiers would need to be incorporated into the LIKE portion of the code to implement this functionality.

Comment: How about using the SQL wildcard "%" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it worked:

```
 $places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE postal_code LIKE ? or place_name LIKE ?  or admin_code1 LIKE ? or admin_name2 LIKE ? or admin_name1 LIKE ?",
    $_GET["geo"] . '%' ,$_GET["geo"] . '%',$_GET["geo"] . '%',$_GET["geo"] . '%',$_GET["geo"] . '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

While using LIKE, you need to use wildcard characters. In this case, assuming that the beggining of the input is correct and only the end is missing you want:

```
LIKE '?%'
```

So in your code that would be:

```
$places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE  places.postal_code LIKE '?%' or place_name = '?%' or admin_code1 = '?%' or admin_name2 = '?%' or admin_name1 = '?%'",
    $_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this like

```
$places = query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE postal_code = ?s or place_name = ?s or admin_code1 = ?s or admin_name2 = ?s or admin_name1 = ?s",
$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"],$_GET["geo"]);
```

Or

```
$places = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE postal_code = '".$_GET["geo"]."' or place_name = '".$_GET["geo"]."' or admin_code1 = '".$_GET["geo"]."' or admin_name2 = '".$_GET["geo"]."' or admin_name1 = '".$_GET["geo"]."'";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those work and they prevent any suggestions at all from appearing in the drop down box even with an exact match. The query returns the following error: Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?s or place_name = ? or admin_code1 = ? or admin_name2 = ? or admin_name1 = ?'